# Xamarin.iOS - custom UIPopoverBackgroundView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I need to implement a custom popover for iOS 6+ using Xamarin.iOS.

So far, everything is working except turning off the default shadow. Here is my implementation:

```
    public class PopoverBackgroundView : UIPopoverBackgroundView
    {
        private UIImageView _arrow, _background;

        public override float ArrowOffset { get; set; }

        public override UIPopoverArrowDirection ArrowDirection { get; set; }

        [Export ("arrowHeight")]
        static new float GetArrowHeight()
        {
            return 39;
        }

        [Export ("arrowBase")]
        static new float GetArrowBase()
        {
            return 80;
        }

        [Export ("contentViewInsets")]
        static new UIEdgeInsets GetContentViewInsets()
        {
            return new UIEdgeInsets (25, 25, 25, 25);
        }

        [Export("wantsDefaultContentAppearance")]
        static new bool WantsDefaultContentAppearance
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public PopoverBackgroundView(IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            _background = new UIImageView { Image = Theme.PopoverBackgroundImage };
            _arrow = new UIImageView { Image = Theme.PopoverArrowImage };

            AddSubview(_background);
            AddSubview(_arrow);
        }

        public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews();

            var arrowFrame = new RectangleF(Frame.Width - GetArrowBase(), -14, GetArrowBase(), GetArrowHeight());
            _arrow.Frame = arrowFrame;

            var backgroundFrame = Frame;
            backgroundFrame.X = 
                backgroundFrame.Y = 0;
            _background.Frame = backgroundFrame;
        }
    }
```

This class is pretty weird, because you have to "override" static Objective-C values. The only way to do this in C# is declaring a `static new` member and adding the `Export` attribute.

Everything is working except for `WantsDefaultContentAppearance`, which is never called. According to Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIPopoverBackgroundView/wantsDefaultContentAppearance), it will disable the default shadow on the popover. Has anyone gotten this to work with Xamarin.iOS? I think it could possibly be a Xamarin bug since all the methods work fine, and this one happens to be a property. The methods in this class seem to be defined as methods "on purpose" in this class, since they would look a lot prettier as properties.

Comment: Apple's `wantsDefaultContentAppearance` is **not** property - but a (static) method (just like `arrowHeight` and `arrowBase`, while `arrowDirection` and `arrowOffset` are (instance) properties.

Comment: Right, so the base class in C#, `UIPopoverBackgroundView`, has `WantsDefaultContentAppearance` defined as a static property. Does this break the export? I tried making a static method just like the others, and it doesn't get called either.

Comment: It *should* not, for a getter, matter in bindings as the signature is identical (setter are another matter). I recall *overriding* the arrow stuff in an app of mine (but that works for you). I can't see anything wrong in the above - so you better file a bug report and attach a test case so we can look if something is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a Xamarin bug, but the iOS APIs were just not working for me.

To fix this, my designer took his shadow off the images and we just kept the default shadow.

Honestly, I think this is better anyway, because Apple took the time to make a pretty shadow--why remove it?